# How to set permission as per user using Django and Python?

Tags: python, django

I need to set permission as per registered user using Django and Python. I have done something but confused whether it is fulfilled my requirement or not. I am providing my code below.

```
class Control(models.Model):
    """docstring for Control"""

    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    control_reactor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    find_reactor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    view_reactor = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    class Meta:
        """docstring for Meta"""
        permissions = (
            ("view_reactor", "can view reactor"),
            ("find_reactor", "can find reactor"),
            ("controll_reactor", "can controll reactor"),
        )
```

I am access those permission using Django decorator function like `@permission_required`. Here I need as per user I will set the 3 permissions but confused that this model class is doing as per requirement.

Answer (score 3):

The meta class defined is just a representation that your model will have only these permissions so it becomes manageable.

You can create permissions programmatically using Permission class from django. From django docs

> User objects have two many-to-many fields: groups and user_permissions. User objects can access their related objects in the same way as any other Django model

Permission models stores all the permission which can be set to a specific user. All you have to do is add the create a permission and add it to user.

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User
content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(BlogPost)
permission = Permission.objects.get(
    codename='change_blogpost',
    content_type=content_type,
)
user.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

The related name is `user_permissions` so you can directly add the permission same as M2M relationships.

Now suppose you want to check permissions

```
user.has_perm('app_name.code_name') # generic example
user.has_perm('myapp.change_blogpost')
```

Now for decorator you can do same

```
@permission_required('app_name.code_name')
```

EDIT: Generally you grant permission when you create a user so the example mentioned above can be put in your views where you signup the user. If you don't want to grant permissions right away then you can make a separate view which grants permission to the user

```
def grant_permissions(request):
    user = request.user
    # then you put the code mentioned above
```

for your case you can either create permissions in you code using permissions model or use meta class.

Just migrate the database to create permissions defined in the meta class.  After migrate don't forget to give permission to user using the code mentioned above using Permissions model Then you can use the permissions in the decorator.

```
@permission_required('view_reactor')
```

- [custom_permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/customizing/#custom-permissions)
- [permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#programmatically-creating-permissions)

Comment: Can you edit as per my permission set. In which file i will define the first  portion of your code and `BlogPost` is the app name right ? Here I need to set three different permission as per different user.

Comment: @satya see the edit.  BlogPost is the app name. Also you need to grant permission to each user explicitly using Permissions model. After migrate get the Permission object and use it to grant a permission to user.

Comment: The permission will be set inside the admin page not any logged in user and you mean `from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission, User
def grant_permissions(request):
    user = request.user
    content_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(plant)
    permission = Permission.objects.get(
       codename='change_plant',
       content_type=content_type,
    )
    user.user_permissions.add(permission)`, I need to write like this in views.py.

Comment: If you want to set permissions in the admin then you have to write some more code to setup admin page and other things but for in general views the above will work. In case of admin you have to get the user from User model and then set the permissions with logic above.

Comment: because for any registered user admin will set the permission. User can not give any permission to ownshelf. It was my requirement actually and those permissions will be checked using decorator function.

Comment: The above is a general solution to the question asked. If you have requirement for admin page then I am afraid to say this but you have to ask another question. General solution is this one and works as expected

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152013/discussion-between-satya-and-arpit-solanki).